# Why hardcode domains in nginx config?

Tags: nginx

I keep reading that in nginx config files, we should hardcode hostnames instead of using variables.

For example:

```
server_name www.example.com example.com;
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

instead of

```
server_name www.example.com example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

I find it surprising that nginx wouldn't cache static config upon start.

Is there official documentation about this somewhere, or is it just anecdotal?

Comment: The two statements perform different functions. `$host` is not a static variable but based on the headers in the original request. If you only host one website, then hardcoding the website name is not an issue, but if you host many websites, you may require a flexible configuration that does not contain the name `example.com`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Point taken I updated the text, I was struggling to find a good example. The question is about the hardcoding itself, I'm not sure if the example is a good one.

Comment: Your second example will not work correctly as you risk redirection to `www.www.example.com`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Lol updated again.

Comment: Again, the two blocks perform different functions. One will ensure that the redirect will always begin with `www.` whereas the other will simply redirect from `http` to `https` keeping the requested hostname unchanged. You could use either, depending on your specific requirements.

Comment: If you can think of a better example :)... I looked for the simplest example for my question.

Comment: Maybe the articles in which you "keep reading" about this have examples? Could you link a few, so we can review their claims directly?

Comment: @ceejayoz Not articles, answers here and on SO

Comment: Same point still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [official documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html).

It refers to variables in general, but the sentiment is clear: hardcode if possible.

> Variables should not be used as template macros. Variables are evaluated in the run-time during the processing of each request, so they are rather costly compared to plain static configuration. Using variables to store static strings is also a bad idea. Instead, a macro expansion and "include" directives should be used to generate configs more easily and it can be done with the external tools, e.g. sed + make or any other common template mechanism.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432888/9971404).